# API to change ownership of file vista

Tags: visual-c++, windows-vista, file-permissions

I have a file created by installer as Administrator owner.
Is there any API that can change the ownership of file on Vista?

Comment: Okay I can add Users to the ACL of file . But "Users" not having write permissions. Can I give Users write permission by some elevate process?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an MSDN article describing how to do that: [Taking Object Ownership in C++ (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379620%28VS.85%29.aspx)